# Action method of liferay portlet container not called from jquery submit

Tags: jquery, liferay

I am trying to submit an action from a javascript function using jquery submit(). 
The action method doesn't get called, but the render method of the controller is called. 
When I copy past the url string (from firebug debugger "<%=deleteURL%>") in the browser window, the action method is called.

What is required for the action method to be called from jquery

The code

```
>>>>>>jsp>>>>>>>>>

<pre><code>
<portlet:actionURL name="deleteObject" var="deleteURL" >
    <portlet:param name="action" value="deleteObject" />
</portlet:actionURL>


<script type="text/javascript">

function <portlet:namespace />deleteObject(id) {
    if (confirm('<%= UnicodeLanguageUtil.get(pageContext, "are-you-sure-you-want-to-delete-the-Object") %>')) {
        debugger;
        jQuery('<form />').attr('action', "<%=deleteURL%>").
            append(jQuery('<input>', {
            'name': 'objectId',
            'value': id,
            'type': 'hidden'
        })).appendTo('body').submit().remove();
    }
}

</script>

</code></pre>

>>>>>>java controller>>>>>>>>>

/**
     * Simply selects the home view to render by returning its name.
     */
    @RenderMapping
    public String render(Locale locale, Model model, RenderRequest req, RenderResponse res) {
        _log.info("Starting render: " + locale.toString());
        ...
        return "listObjects";
    }

    @ActionMapping(params = "action=deleteObject")
    public void deleteObject(Locale locale, Model model, PortletRequest req, PortletResponse res) throws PortalException, SystemException {
        _log.info("Starting deleteObject: " + locale.toString() + ":" + model);
        ....
    }
```

Comment: can you provide proper jsp code snippet here

Comment: By default forms submit as a `get` request. You must specify `method="post"`.